# php optional assosciative array value

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to skip array value or any other way around.
I know , we can either put it to null or ' '. But I have many array keys & very few keys with a value.
In the below array , only Iconpicker is needed a value , setting all other keys to null or an empty array is an arduous task.

Instead of setting all the keys to null

```
$array =  array(
        'active'    => null,
        'required'  => null,
        'show_label'=> null,
        'label_text'=> null,
        'default'   => null,
        'iconpicker'=> array(
            'args' => '11'
        ),
        'placeholder'=> null,
        'min_char'  => null,
        'max_char'  => null,
    ),
```

I want to keep it simple

```
$array = array(
    'active',
    'required',
    'show_label',
    'label_text',
    'default',
    'iconpicker' => array(
        'other' => 'test',
    ),
    'placeholder',
    'min_char',
    'max_char'
),
```

This is just an example , there are many more keys. I process this array as an argument to a function , so it should be dynamic.

```
    foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
        generate_settings( $key, $value )
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of exactly what you want as the outcome? And just to confirm the key `iconpicker` could be anything, for example `'something' = array(1,2)` would be just as valid as the `iconpicker` array?

Comment: Correct ! it can be any key. The main question is how to skip a value ? Like instead of 'active' => null , I just want to keep it 'active', 'required' & then If i need to mention a value like in 'iconpicker' key

Comment: You can't skip a value if you want to keep the key as a key

Comment: I get that , but if you skip a key , php still processes it. Only the format changes & it converts it to normal array with index key. Try print_r the above array

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to initialise all the keys of an array when defining the array in PHP, for example, you can do this:

```
$a['iconpicker'] = array('other' => 'test');

echo $a['iconpicker']['other'];
```

And then later in the code do something like:

```
$a['active'] = null;
$a['key'] = 'value';
```

And now:

```
var_dump($a);
```

Will display:

```
array(3) {  
    ["iconpicker"]=>  array(1) {
        ["other"]=>  string(4) "test"
    }
    ["active"]=>  NULL
    ["key"]=>  string(3) "val"
}
```

PHP is very dynamic like this. Just add or remove to an array as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below, it will remove all other keys except 'iconpicker' key-value pair

```
 $array = array(
        'active',
        'required',
        'show_label',
        'label_text',
        'default',
        'iconpicker' => array(
            'other' => 'test'
        ),
        'placeholder',
        'min_char',
        'max_char'
    );
 print_r(array_intersect_key($array, array('iconpicker' => '')));
```

Comment: I don't want to remove other keys. Iconpicker was just an example , there can be other keys with a value.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? please make your question more crystal clear.